# как сгенерировать JSON из JSONSchema в Python

Tags: python, json

Занимаемся микросервисами, которые обмениваются друг с другом сообщениями в формате JSON. Как-то сами пришли к использованию JSONSchema для генерации. Для генерации использовали язык JAVA и все было хорошо, если рядом разработчик. Но как быть аналитику, который согласовывает поля с заказчиком? Ему нужно оперативное средство для генерации сообщения и демонстрации его заказчику. Ну... первое что приходит на ум, это старая добрая AltovaXMLSpy. Прекрасное средство, но к сожалению платное. Проработав месяц, оно перестает работать. Второе средство, это условно бесплатный LiquidStudio2020. Не альтова, конечно, но все же - генерирует и визуализирует. Но..спустя 15 дней, основные функции, без оплаты лицензии, становятся недоступными.

И вот возникла идея написать скрипт на языке Python. Нашли библиотеку JSONSchema, даже... но нигде не описано, как в ней имея схему сгенерировать сообщение. Складывается ощущение, что это невозможно или мы мы используем не ту библиотеку. Сразу скажу, онлайн генераторы предлагать не стоит. У нас сложная структура объектов в JSONSchema, связанных через " $ref". Есть ли у кого-нибудь подобный опыт генерации сообщений в формате JSON?

Comment: Задача осталось непонятной, что из чего и зачем нужно сгенерировать и как это всё связано с JSONSchema. Также непонятно, почему какие-то там аналитики вообще имеют право вмешиваться в технические поля — по имеющемуся описанию складывается ощущение, будто у вас какие-то проблемы с архитектурой проекта и вы что-то делаете сильно неправильно

Comment: я вам объясню. JSONschema используется для представления модели данных. Аналитик анализирует что ему нужно передать и что получить. Он строит JSONschemы запроса и соотвественно ответа. С дургой стороны заказчиком является бизнес, с который ставит задачу. Для бизнеса JSONschema это не очень информативно, ну не будут они в ней разбираться. Им нужно показать само сообщение - какие поля, в какой структуре где, как и что передают. Поэтому аналитику нужно уметь оперативно генерировать сообщение по схеме..как-то так)